# Language Issue with QnA MAker KB

Tags: azure-qna-maker

**Background**
I am having different KB's created within different QnA Maker service as part of dev& staging environment.
My staging KB's were functional and working properly. Recently we provisioned dev environment on the similar lines as Staging environment and created, exported & imported all the KB's from staging to dev environment.

**Issue**
My Dev environment is not giving me correct responses compared to staging env when I am testing using QnA Maker Test in QnA Maker portal.

**Analysis**
When I am creating any KB in dev environment, I have selected the language as Japansese. When I am trying to fetch the KB details using QnA Maker API "https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/qnamaker/v4.0/knowledgebases/", I am getting the language as Japanese.
But when I import the data using xlsx or tsv file in the same KB & then query KB details, I get the language as English.

What can be the issue ? Same is not  the case with Staging KB.

Comment: When you create your KB, does the language reflect as Japanese on the service settings page in the QnA Maker?